# Merge node stems of two voices in denemo

Tags: lilypond

I have this minimum working example generated with denemo. As you may see, there are two staff with two voices each.

[image: minimum working example]

Now I want to merge the note stems in each staff and I don't find how to do it. The result should look like this:

[image: wished result]

My denemo file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<score xmlns="http://denemo.org/xmlns/Denemo" version="8">
  <thumbnail>
    <first-staff>1</first-staff>
    <last-staff>3</last-staff>
    <first-measure>1</first-measure>
    <last-measure>3</last-measure>
    <first-obj>0</first-obj>
    <last-obj>2147483647</last-obj>
  </thumbnail>
  <lilycontrol>
    <papersize>a4</papersize>
    <lilyversion>2.22</lilyversion>
    <fontsize>18</fontsize>
    <orientation>1</orientation>
    <total-edit-time>8421</total-edit-time>
    <score-directives>
      <directive>
        <tag>ScoreIndent</tag>
        <prefix>\layout {indent = 0.0}
</prefix>
        <display>indent=0.0</display>
        <data>0.0</data>
        <override>4</override>
      </directive>
    </score-directives>
  </lilycontrol>
  <movement-number>1</movement-number>
  <movement>
    <edit-info>
      <staffno>1</staffno>
      <measureno>1</measureno>
      <cursorposition>1</cursorposition>
      <tonalcenter>0</tonalcenter>
      <zoom>100</zoom>
      <system-height>97</system-height>
      <page-zoom>50</page-zoom>
      <page-system-height>25</page-system-height>
      <page-width>1846</page-width>
      <page-height>1016</page-height>
      <measure-width>150</measure-width>
    </edit-info>
    <score-info>
      <tempo>
        <duration>
          <numerator>1</numerator>
          <denominator>4</denominator>
        </duration>
        <bpm>120</bpm>
      </tempo>
    </score-info>
    <staves>
      <staff id="id0"></staff>
      <staff id="id1"></staff>
    </staves>
    <voices>
      <voice id="id2">
        <voice-info>
          <voice-name>Part 1</voice-name>
          <first-measure-number>1</first-measure-number>
        </voice-info>
        <initial-voice-params>
          <staff-ref staff="id0"></staff-ref>
          <clef name="treble"></clef>
          <key-signature>
            <modal-key-signature note-name="D" mode="minor"></modal-key-signature>
          </key-signature>
          <time-signature>
            <simple-time-signature>
              <numerator>3</numerator>
              <denominator>4</denominator>
            </simple-time-signature>
          </time-signature>
        </initial-voice-params>
        <voice-props>
          <number-of-lines>5</number-of-lines>
          <voice-control>1</voice-control>
          <transpose>0</transpose>
          <instrument></instrument>
          <device-port>NONE</device-port>
          <volume>127</volume>
          <override_volume>0</override_volume>
          <mute>0</mute>
          <midi_prognum>0</midi_prognum>
          <midi_channel>0</midi_channel>
          <hasfigures>0</hasfigures>
          <hasfakechords>0</hasfakechords>
          <verses>
            <verse>Nimm al --  les von mir, was mich fern -- hält von dir. Gib al -- les mir, was mich hin -- führt zu dir. Le -- ben -- di -- ger Gott, nimm mich mir und gib mich ganz __ zu ei -- gen dir. Nimm</verse>
          </verses>
        </voice-props>
        <measures>
          <measure>
            <chord show="true" id="id3">
              <duration base="quarter"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id4">
                  <middle-c-offset>3</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id5">
              <duration base="quarter"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id6">
                  <middle-c-offset>3</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id7">
              <duration base="quarter"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id8">
                  <middle-c-offset>4</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
          </measure>
          <measure>
            <chord show="true" id="id9">
              <duration base="half"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id10">
                  <middle-c-offset>5</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id11">
              <duration base="eighth"></duration>
              <directives>
                <directive>
                  <tag>Beam</tag>
                  <postfix>[</postfix>
                  <display>[</display>
                  <tx>6</tx>
                </directive>
              </directives>
              <notes>
                <note id="id12">
                  <middle-c-offset>5</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id13">
              <duration base="eighth"></duration>
              <directives>
                <directive>
                  <tag>Beam</tag>
                  <postfix>]</postfix>
                  <display>]</display>
                  <tx>6</tx>
                </directive>
              </directives>
              <notes>
                <note id="id14">
                  <middle-c-offset>4</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
          </measure>
        </measures>
      </voice>
      <voice id="id15">
        <voice-info>
          <voice-name>Part 1</voice-name>
          <first-measure-number>1</first-measure-number>
        </voice-info>
        <initial-voice-params>
          <staff-ref staff="id0"></staff-ref>
          <clef name="treble"></clef>
          <key-signature>
            <modal-key-signature note-name="D" mode="minor"></modal-key-signature>
          </key-signature>
          <time-signature>
            <simple-time-signature>
              <numerator>3</numerator>
              <denominator>4</denominator>
            </simple-time-signature>
          </time-signature>
        </initial-voice-params>
        <voice-props>
          <number-of-lines>5</number-of-lines>
          <voice-control>3</voice-control>
          <transpose>0</transpose>
          <instrument></instrument>
          <device-port>NONE</device-port>
          <volume>127</volume>
          <override_volume>0</override_volume>
          <mute>0</mute>
          <midi_prognum>0</midi_prognum>
          <midi_channel>0</midi_channel>
          <hasfigures>0</hasfigures>
          <hasfakechords>0</hasfakechords>
        </voice-props>
        <measures>
          <measure>
            <chord show="true" id="id16">
              <duration base="quarter"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id17">
                  <middle-c-offset>1</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id18">
              <duration base="quarter"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id19">
                  <middle-c-offset>1</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id20">
              <duration base="quarter"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id21">
                  <middle-c-offset>2</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
          </measure>
          <measure>
            <chord show="true" id="id22">
              <duration base="half"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id23">
                  <middle-c-offset>3</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id24">
              <duration base="eighth"></duration>
              <directives>
                <directive>
                  <tag>Beam</tag>
                  <postfix>[</postfix>
                  <display>[</display>
                  <tx>6</tx>
                </directive>
              </directives>
              <notes>
                <note id="id25">
                  <middle-c-offset>2</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id26">
              <duration base="eighth"></duration>
              <directives>
                <directive>
                  <tag>Beam</tag>
                  <postfix>]</postfix>
                  <display>]</display>
                  <tx>6</tx>
                </directive>
              </directives>
              <notes>
                <note id="id27">
                  <middle-c-offset>2</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
          </measure>
        </measures>
      </voice>
      <voice id="id28">
        <voice-info>
          <voice-name>unnamed</voice-name>
          <first-measure-number>1</first-measure-number>
        </voice-info>
        <initial-voice-params>
          <staff-ref staff="id1"></staff-ref>
          <clef name="bass"></clef>
          <key-signature>
            <modal-key-signature note-name="D" mode="minor"></modal-key-signature>
          </key-signature>
          <time-signature>
            <simple-time-signature>
              <numerator>3</numerator>
              <denominator>4</denominator>
            </simple-time-signature>
          </time-signature>
        </initial-voice-params>
        <voice-props>
          <number-of-lines>5</number-of-lines>
          <voice-control>1</voice-control>
          <transpose>0</transpose>
          <instrument></instrument>
          <device-port>NONE</device-port>
          <volume>127</volume>
          <override_volume>0</override_volume>
          <mute>0</mute>
          <midi_prognum>0</midi_prognum>
          <midi_channel>1</midi_channel>
          <hasfigures>0</hasfigures>
          <hasfakechords>0</hasfakechords>
          <staff-directives>
            <directive>
              <tag>InstrumentName</tag>
              <prefix>instrumentName = \markup {  \with-url #'"scheme:(d-GoToPosition 1 2 1 1)(let ((choice (d-PopupMenu (list (cons (_ \"Change Name\") d-InstrumentName)   (cons (_ \"Change Indent\") d-ScoreIndent)))))
                            (if choice (choice)))    " "" }</prefix>
              <override>22</override>
            </directive>
          </staff-directives>
          <voice-directives>
            <directive>
              <tag>InitialVoice</tag>
              <postfix>\voiceFour</postfix>
              <display>Voice Four</display>
              <override>4</override>
            </directive>
          </voice-directives>
        </voice-props>
        <measures>
          <measure>
            <chord show="true" id="id29">
              <duration base="quarter"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id30">
                  <middle-c-offset>-2</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id31">
              <duration base="quarter"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id32">
                  <middle-c-offset>-2</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id33">
              <duration base="quarter"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id34">
                  <middle-c-offset>0</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
          </measure>
          <measure>
            <chord show="true" id="id35">
              <duration base="half"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id36">
                  <middle-c-offset>0</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id37">
              <duration base="eighth"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id38">
                  <middle-c-offset>0</middle-c-offset>
                  <accidental name="sharp" show="true"></accidental>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id39">
              <duration base="eighth"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id40">
                  <middle-c-offset>0</middle-c-offset>
                  <accidental name="sharp" show="false"></accidental>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
          </measure>
        </measures>
      </voice>
      <voice id="id41">
        <voice-info>
          <voice-name>unnamed</voice-name>
          <first-measure-number>1</first-measure-number>
        </voice-info>
        <initial-voice-params>
          <staff-ref staff="id1"></staff-ref>
          <clef name="bass"></clef>
          <key-signature>
            <modal-key-signature note-name="D" mode="minor"></modal-key-signature>
          </key-signature>
          <time-signature>
            <simple-time-signature>
              <numerator>3</numerator>
              <denominator>4</denominator>
            </simple-time-signature>
          </time-signature>
        </initial-voice-params>
        <voice-props>
          <number-of-lines>5</number-of-lines>
          <voice-control>3</voice-control>
          <transpose>0</transpose>
          <instrument></instrument>
          <device-port>NONE</device-port>
          <volume>127</volume>
          <override_volume>0</override_volume>
          <mute>0</mute>
          <midi_prognum>0</midi_prognum>
          <midi_channel>1</midi_channel>
          <hasfigures>0</hasfigures>
          <hasfakechords>0</hasfakechords>
        </voice-props>
        <measures>
          <measure>
            <chord show="true" id="id42">
              <duration base="quarter"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id43">
                  <middle-c-offset>-6</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id44">
              <duration base="quarter"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id45">
                  <middle-c-offset>-6</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id46">
              <duration base="quarter"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id47">
                  <middle-c-offset>-7</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
          </measure>
          <measure>
            <chord show="true" id="id48">
              <duration base="half"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id49">
                  <middle-c-offset>-4</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id50">
              <duration base="eighth"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id51">
                  <middle-c-offset>-9</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
            <chord show="true" id="id52">
              <duration base="eighth"></duration>
              <notes>
                <note id="id53">
                  <middle-c-offset>-9</middle-c-offset>
                </note>
              </notes>
            </chord>
          </measure>
        </measures>
      </voice>
    </voices>
  </movement>
</score>
```

I would appreciate any help. Since denemo has no own tag I used LilyPond.

### Update 1

The command from rshann worked only if I run it on every voice. The result comes close, but on the seconds staff is still something wrong.

[image: result Update 1]

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer to differentiate voices by the stem direction, i.e., soprano up, alto down, tenor up, bass down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little time of trial and error I set the first and second voice via Object Menu ▶ Staffs/Voices ▶ Initial Voice One and the third and fourth voice as Voice Forth. This is not 100 percent what I wanted, but comes close to it.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't really voices, they are chords. A voice

- is always notated with stems separated from the other voices,
- can have different rhythms than the other voices.

Chords

- join notes from the same voice
- are written with shared stems.

Therefore, using a single voice on both staves is conceptually correct, not something of a workaround.

Comment: This was only a short MWE. Later on, there will be notes with different rhythms. So it's like a mixing between separate voices and chords.
The full song you can find [here](http://hansruedi-vetsch.blogspot.com/2017/12/taize-gib-mich-ganz-zu-eigen-dir.html).

Comment: In LilyPond, \partCombine would be ideal for that, but I don't know if Denemo has an interface to it.

Answer (score 0):

Command: No Horizontal Shifts
Turns off horizontal displacement of notes (which avoid collisions between parts)
Location: Object Menu ▶ Staffs/Voices ▶ Voices
Internal Name: ShiftOff

email denemo-devel@gnu.org for questions like this!